# I have 1M records -some records are from data loader

Tags: rest-api

I have 1M records -some records are from data loader and there is no picklist restriction  I want to see uniuqe values for account object with that perticular values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this instead of direct assign it to a variable you first need to assign it to a List. Then check the size and if it is greater then 0 then use the Id.

```
List<recordtype> recrodtypeList=[select  recordtype.id from recordtype where recordtype.name=:obj.cse.recTypeId limit 1]; 
if(recrodtypeList.size() > 0) {
    recrodtypeName = recrodtypeList[0].Id
}
```

Comment: id devRecordTypeId;
                  devRecordTypeId = (schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(development ).getRecordTypeId());   how can i take the devRecordTypeId in a list.

Comment: `Schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName( )` it will return a map from there you can get the List.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than querying the `recordTypeId` via SOQL, you could utilize this method to retrieve recordtypeId

```
public static Id findRecordTypeId(String recordTypeDevName){
    return Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName()
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Case;
    Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = d.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    if(rtMapByName.containsKey(recordTypeDevName))
    {
        return rtMapByName.get(recordTypeDevName).getRecordTypeId();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

case  cases=new case();                
System.debug('inside IF::');
cases.status=obj.cse.Status;
cases.Origin=obj.cse.Origin;
cases.RecordTypeId= findRecordTypeId(obj.cse.recTypeId);
cases.enq_typ=obj.cse.enquiry;

Insert cases;
RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Case created successfully');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.but if my recordtype is incorrect then its throwing Attempt to de-reference a null object error .instead of it needs to go to else and throw error i want..